# Method if linked list is palindrome in generic class

Tags: java, list, linked-list

There seems to be a lot of answers to this question, but not a single one that could have helped me. I need to check if a singly linked list is a palindrome, and write a method for it in the generic class, but somehow I am missing a point because the main throws an exception. I am using the algorithm where you separate the list on half and check of they are the same. Here is my program.

The method is:

```
public boolean isPalindrome() {
        Node<T> slow_ptr = head;
        Node<T> fast_ptr = head;
        Node<T> mid_node = null;
        while (true) {
            fast_ptr = fast_ptr.next.next;
            if (fast_ptr.next == null) {
                mid_node = slow_ptr.next.next;
                break;
            }
            if (fast_ptr == null) { //in eclipse it says here Dead code?
                mid_node = slow_ptr.next;
                break;
            }
            slow_ptr = slow_ptr.next;
        }
        while (head != null && mid_node != null) {
            if (head != mid_node)
                return false;
            head = head.next;
            mid_node = mid_node.next;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

and the main is this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Palindrome {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
        int n = in.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int elem = in.nextInt();
            list.add(elem);
        }
        boolean is_pal = list.isPalindrome();
        if (is_pal) System.out.println("Palindrome");
        else System.out.println("Not a palindrom");
    }
}
```

Comment: is head initialized?

Comment: Probably dead code because if your `fast_ptr` was `null` you just raised a `NullPointerException` by trying to access `null.next` in the previous condition

Comment: yes, head is initialized at null. Could sb help me how to fix this? Thanks. And, yes it was a NullPointerException that was thrown